# pod setup --verbose does not do anything

Tags: cocoa, installation, cocoapods, verbose

iMac:~ pierre-henri$ pod setup --verbose
iMac:~ pierre-henri$

I don't get more than that, the setup was successfull?
thank you for your help

Pierre-Henri

Comment: There is a problem with Catalina, you need downgrade Pod.

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/State-of-Catalina-Support

Answer (score 0):

follow these commands to fix the problem

sudo gem uninstall cocoapods

sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.7.5

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you explain your answer?